# RunImpersonated can't load dependencies

Tags: c#, impersonation, sqlclient

I am using WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated to execute SQL query. When impersonated my program can't load any modules, so I am loading them before impersonation (Is there any way to load them even when impersonated?). But when I call SqlConnection.Open() program throws error "dll not found". As I understand it can't found "sni.dll" which is called from System.Data.SqlClient. Is there any way to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

The account that you impersonated does not have read access to the folders containing the package Dlls. To resolve this issue, you can grant read access for the account you want to impersonate to all your application folders.